# C++ OBJ file parser

Tags: c++, opengl

I am making a file parser for the OBJ files and everything is going into the correct place but for some reason it doesn't run till the end of the file.

```
    void loader::readIn()
{
    //!takes in the all the data and 
    //!puts in string first.
    std::string line;

    while(!myFile.eof())
    {

        linetype = unknown;//enum set to uknown
        line.clear(); // clear line
        ss.clear();  // clear string stream
        std::getline(myFile,line); //intake line , to string line

        //found = line.find("v "); //enum to check the line type i,e Face ,vertex
        if(line[0] == 'v') //! check to see if the first char is v
           {
             linetype = vertex;   

           }

    //  found = line.find("f ");
        if(line[0] == 'f') //! checkl to see if the first char is f
        {
            linetype = face;

        }

    //  found = line.find("vn ");
        if(line[0] == 'vn') //! checkl to see if the first char is vn 
        {

            linetype = vertexNormal;

        }
        //  found = line.find("vt ")
        if(line[0] == 'vt') //! checkl to see if the first char is vt
        {
            linetype = vertexTexture;

        }

            if(line[0] == ' ' || '#') // if the start of the line is empty or a #
        {
            line.clear();   //clear line
                std::getline(myFile,line); // intake the next line
        }



        switch(linetype)
        { 
        case vertex:     //!stores the verrtex floats in vert.

            ss >> vertexFloat[0] >> vertexFloat[1] >> vertexFloat[2];
            verts.push_back(new coordinate(vertexFloat[0],vertexFloat[1],vertexFloat[2])); //creates new coord
            linetype = unknown;
            break;

        case face:
            int n; // these are the counters for the float arrays
            int m;
            int b;
            n = 0;
            m = 0;
            b = 0;
            int faces[3];   //temperary float array
            int faceText[3];
            int faceNorm[3];
            ss.str(line);  //string stream  intake line
            ss.ignore(1); 
            while( !ss.eof())
            {

                ss >> faces[n]; // intake first umber
                n++;

                 if(ss.peek() == '/')
                 {
                     ss.ignore(1);

                     if(ss.peek() != '/')
                    { 
                      ss >> faceText[m];
                      m++;
                     }
                 }

                ss.ignore(1);
                ss >> faceNorm[b];
                b++;

             }


            for( int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i)
            {
            totalFaces.push_back(faces[i]);  // push back all the ints on the correct
            faceTexture.push_back(faceText[i]); // vector
            faceNormal.push_back(faceNorm[i]);
            }
            break;
```

This is the code it takes in the first 3 lines then just stops. I am checking the totalFaces vector which takes in the first number of each set of 3.

```
**f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9
f 1/2/3 4//6 7/8/9**
```

is my obj file.

Comment: you can use while(std::getline(myFile, line)){..your code here..}

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use eof(). Look my code:

```
void Mesh::LoadObjModel(const char *filename)
{
  std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in);
  if (!in)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);

    }
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(in, line))
  {
    //check v for vertices
     if (line.substr(0,2)=="v "){
        std::istringstream v(line.substr(2));
        glm::vec3 vert;
        double x,y,z;
        v>>x;v>>y;v>>z;
        vert=glm::vec3(x,y,z);
        vertices.push_back(vert);
  }
  //check for texture co-ordinate
  else if(line.substr(0,2)=="vt"){

      std::istringstream v(line.substr(3));
      glm::vec2 tex;
      int U,V;
      v>>U;v>>V;
      tex=glm::vec2(U,V);
      texture.push_back(tex);

  }
  //check for faces
  else if(line.substr(0,2)=="f "){
    int a,b,c; //to store mesh index
    int A,B,C; //to store texture index
    //std::istringstream v;
  //v.str(line.substr(2));
  const char* chh=line.c_str();
    sscanf (chh, "f %i/%i %i/%i %i/%i",&a,&A,&b,&B,&c,&C); //here it read the line start with f and store the corresponding values in the variables

    //v>>a;v>>b;v>>c;
    a--;b--;c--;
    A--;B--;C--;
    //std::cout<<a<<b<<c<<A<<B<<C;
    faceIndex.push_back(a);textureIndex.push_back(A);
    faceIndex.push_back(b);textureIndex.push_back(B);
    faceIndex.push_back(c);textureIndex.push_back(C);
  }

}
//the mesh data is finally calculated here
for(unsigned int i=0;i<faceIndex.size();i++)
{
    glm::vec3 meshData;
    glm::vec2 texData;
    meshData=glm::vec3(vertices[faceIndex[i]].x,vertices[faceIndex[i]].y,vertices[faceIndex[i]].z);
    texData=glm::vec2(texture[textureIndex[i]].x,texture[textureIndex[i]].y);
    meshVertices.push_back(meshData);
    texCoord.push_back(texData);
}

}
```

In above sample code the 'Vn' for normal is missing. You can add another condition to check 'Vn' similar to other. I hope this could solve you problem. If you need complete sample program then look [here](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/07/modern-opengl3d-model-obj-loaderparser.html).

Comment: why are you decrementing `a`,`b`,`c`,`A`,`B` and `C`.

Comment: @Ask, In obj file Index starts with 1 not with zero that's way I decremented .

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect to check `eof()` in the loop condition. It's not a prediction, it indicates that the previous read failed because of EOF. E.g. even an empty file doesn't start with `.eof` true.

Also, 'vn' is neither one character nor two characters. `line[0]` definitely is one character and obviously cannot equal the two characters "vn".

Comment: What alternatives could i use to eof() to make it read to the end of the file.

Comment: Just try to read, and check the result of the stream afterwards. If it's still good, the read succeeded and the string is OK. If not, you're done. That easy. To make it really convenient, `std::getline(stream, line)` returns the stream which you can test directly - a stream converts to `true` when it's still good.